# Append additional variable to formData

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I append `dataid` to the `formData` so that AJAX POST's both? I have tried `formData.append('id', dataid);` and `formData = formData.append('id', dataid);`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#insert_screen').on("submit", function(event) {
    var dataid = $("#res option:selected").attr('data-value');
    console.log("Value", dataid);

    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $('form')[2];
    var formData = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
      url: "insert_new_screen.php",
      data: formData,
      method: "POST",
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('#insert').val("Inserting");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#add_screen_modal').modal('hide');
        window.location.reload();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

UPDATE:

Below is the code I managed to get working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#insert_screen').on("submit", function(event){
  var dataid = $("#res option:selected").attr('data-value');
  console.log("Value", dataid);
  event.preventDefault();  
  var form = $('form')[2]; 
  var formData = new FormData(form);
  formData.append("RecordID", dataid);
  $.ajax({  
    url:"insert_new_screen.php",
    data: formData,
    method:"POST",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,  
        beforeSend:function(){  
      $('#insert').val("Inserting");  
    },  
    success:function(data){  
      $('#add_screen_modal').modal('hide');
      window.location.reload();
    }  
  });  
    });
});
```

Many thanks to all those who gave me help. I hope this helps other.

Comment: `formData.append('id', dataid)` is the correct method. How have you determined that it's not working?

Comment: Also note that `FormData` is a Javascript construct, not jQuery, so I've re-tagged your question

Comment: why cant you use a form element with input type="hidden" field and change this field value based on the selection you made and then submit the form.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Hi, when the form is POSTED and I them look in at the header in the browser console network, none of the data is posted. In fact there is no Form section. If I remove the "append" them the From section displays what has been posted.

Comment: Check the data server side. FormData encodes the content so it's not easily readable.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan The response from the server is:Array
(
)
SELECT * FROM signage_screen_types WHERE RecordID = -1